# Implementing Custom Expression Handling with Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

In my Java Spring Boot 3 application, I want to use Spring Security with `@PreAuthorize` / `@PostAuthorize`. For some reason, the Keycloak-generated tokens I receive do not have Roles under `Authorities` as Spring expects them, but under a `"realm_access"` attribute.
So, I decided to go ahead and implement a custom Expession handler, following pretty much what I found in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#customizing-expression-handling

So, some code
**Expression Root**

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot
        extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    public boolean hasRealmRole(String role) {
        var principal = ((OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal)this.getPrincipal());
        if (principal == null) {
            return false;
        }

        var realmAccess = (JSONObject)principal.getAttribute("realm_access");
        if (realmAccess == null) {
            return false;
        }

        var roles = (JSONArray)realmAccess.get("roles");
        if (roles == null || roles.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        return roles.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.equals(role));
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Expression Handler**

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(
            Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root =
                new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }
}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    // Cloud config related endpoint
                    .requestMatchers("/configuration/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRealmRole('FOOBAR')")
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Asset> getAsset(@UUIDConstraint @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    ...
```

and finally, the **Beans** based on the Spring reference added above

```
@Configuration
public class BaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        return new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        var handler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Now, when I am sending a request to the `/GET` endpoint, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasRealmRole('FOOBAR')'  
...  
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasRealmRole(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

Any idea why my `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` is not properly registered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, what you did is not quite adapted to authorities mapping: there are authentication (and authorities) converters for that. I have written a tutorial for configuring a quite universal authorities mapper [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-resource-server). It is compatible with Keycloak roles defined at realm level (those you found in `realm_access.roles` claim) as well as client level (`resource-access.{client-id}.roles` claims).

Enriching the security SpEL DSL is actually a bit tricky (I had to copy a Spring protected class to get it working) and should be used when needing more than **R**ole **B**ased **A**ccess **C**ontrol. I have [another tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication) for that, but it is quite adherent to my libs and starters (the previous one I linked is not).

Here is a sample expression handler configuration:

```java
@Bean
static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    return new C4MethodSecurityExpressionHandler(ProxiesMethodSecurityExpressionRoot::new);
}
```

With this expression root:

```java
static final class ProxiesMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends C4MethodSecurityExpressionRoot {

    public boolean is(String preferredUsername) {
        return Objects.equals(preferredUsername, getAuthentication().getName());
    }

    public Proxy onBehalfOf(String proxiedUsername) {
        return get(ProxiesAuthentication.class).map(a -> a.getProxyFor(proxiedUsername))
                .orElse(new Proxy(proxiedUsername, getAuthentication().getName(), List.of()));
    }

    public boolean isNice() {
        return hasAnyAuthority("NICE", "SUPER_COOL");
    }
}
```

And here is the code I had to copy from Spring Security:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class C4MethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    private final Supplier<C4MethodSecurityExpressionRoot> expressionRootSupplier;

    /**
     * Creates the root object for expression evaluation.
     */
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
            MethodInvocation invocation) {
        return createSecurityExpressionRoot(() -> authentication, invocation);
    }

    @Override
    public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, MethodInvocation mi) {
        var root = createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, mi);
        var ctx = new C4MethodSecurityEvaluationContext(root, mi, getParameterNameDiscoverer());
        ctx.setBeanResolver(getBeanResolver());
        return ctx;
    }

    private MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Supplier<Authentication> authentication,
            MethodInvocation invocation) {
        final var root = expressionRootSupplier.get();
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(getTrustResolver());
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        root.setDefaultRolePrefix(getDefaultRolePrefix());
        return root;
    }

    static class C4MethodSecurityEvaluationContext extends MethodBasedEvaluationContext {

        C4MethodSecurityEvaluationContext(MethodSecurityExpressionOperations root, MethodInvocation mi,
                ParameterNameDiscoverer parameterNameDiscoverer) {
            super(root, getSpecificMethod(mi), mi.getArguments(), parameterNameDiscoverer);
        }

        private static Method getSpecificMethod(MethodInvocation mi) {
            return AopUtils.getMostSpecificMethod(mi.getMethod(), AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(mi.getThis()));
        }

    }

}
```

```java
public class C4MethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    private Object filterObject;
    private Object returnObject;
    private Object target;

    public C4MethodSecurityExpressionRoot() {
        super(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <T extends Authentication> Optional<T> get(Class<T> expectedAuthType) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getAuthentication()).map(a -> a.getClass().isAssignableFrom(expectedAuthType) ? (T) a : null).flatMap(Optional::ofNullable);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterObject(Object filterObject) {
        this.filterObject = filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFilterObject() {
        return filterObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject) {
        this.returnObject = returnObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getReturnObject() {
        return returnObject;
    }

    public void setThis(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getThis() {
        return target;
    }

}
```

Comment: great work, thank you! 
Enriching the security SpEL DSL is indeed much trickier than I expected (or I should expect I guess), tweaking your implementation to work with my code was quite fast and straightforward however

Comment: This really worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I am using your spring-addons library and this works perfectly. Thank you.